# Getting chrome console to show object values as they were

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I just noticed in the chrome console a little icon saying "Value below evaluated just now."

[image]

So I wanted to do a test to see if the console was in fact evaluating object when displayed or when expanded. So I did the following. and I didn't expand the object until I was finished and as you can see it shows 1999 not 2.

[image]

In many cases, I want to know the state of objects when I log them not after they are manipulated. How can you get the console to show the state of the object as it was when it was logged and not after it is expanded?

Comment: You can output a copy of the object via `Object.assign` or various framework deep/shallow copy methods like jQuery.extend etc. Or simply use JSON.stringify.

Comment: Yeah, I might have to.